# How do I paginate my result query in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, pagination

I am trying to implement a pagination functionality with JPA but I am having trouble.

I can get and set the first and last numbers on the link e.g. localhost:8000/?first=11&last=20.

As you can see, I am trying to get the items starting at row 11 and ending at row 20, however, I am getting all the results starting from first but with a total amount of last e.g. starting at 10 but with 20 results as opposed to the desired 10.

I am using:

```
query.setFirstResult(firstRowNumber - 1).setMaxResults(lastRowNumber);
```

How do I therefore limit my results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this:

```
query
  .setFirstResult(firstRowNumber - 1)
  .setMaxResults(lastRowNumber - firstRowNumber + 1);
```

Notice that the method is named `setMaxResults()` (total number), not `setLastResult()`. Have a look at awesome [spring-data-jpa](/questions/tagged/spring-data-jpa) which handles paging very nicely.